# How to override footer.tpl in prestashop 1.6 back office?

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I want to override 'footer.tpl' template file in the back office of prestashop 1.6 and remove the social network links from it.
how can i do this? is it possible to do this using modules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don´t need to override anything. Simply disable the "Blocksocial" module and all the social links will disappear. To disable the module go to backoffice->modules->blocksocial->deactivate